# Multiple inheritance of QApplication and QAbstractNativeEventFilter

Tags: qt

I want to filter the USB device insert/removal events in my Qt application. So I need to use `installNativeEventFilter()` to install a native even filter (derived from `QAbstractNativeEventFilter`) to my app. The problem is I need emit some signals from my event filter, and connect them to the slots in my app. So, if I can inherent from both `QApplication` and `QAbstractNativeEventFilter`, then both the signals and slots are in the same class, and it's more convenient to connect them. But is the code below safe or not?

```
class QApp  : public QApplication, public QAbstractNativeEventFilter
{
    virtual bool nativeEventFilter(const QByteArray &eventType, void *message, long *) Q_DECL_OVERRIDE;
signals:
    void deviceChanged();
    ...
};

QApp a(argc, argv);
a.installNativeEventFilter( &a );
```

Comment: It is safe, but you don't need to inherit both. Just create an `EventFilter` class with `QAbstractNativeEventFilter` base.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why would you want to derive from `QApplication`? To emit signals, all you need is to derive from `QObject`:

```
class NativeEventFilter : public QObject, public QAbstractNativeEventFilter {
  Q_OBJECT
  ...
public:
  Q_SIGNAL void signal1();
  explicit NativeEventFilter(QObject * parent = 0) : QObject(parent) {}
  bool nativeEventFilter(const QByteArray & et, void * msg, long * result) override {
    ...
  };
  ...
};

int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
  QApplication app(argc, argv);
  NativeEventFilter filter;
  app.installNativeEventFilter(&filter);
  ...
  return app.exec();
}
```